# Can't find .codeblocks in home directory

Tags: 18.04, files, configuration, code-blocks

`default.conf` should be in `.codeblocks` which is a hidden directory in home directory. But I can't find either `default.conf` or `.codeblocks` on my PC. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: use `ls -a` inside your terminal to see hidden folders / files, or using Nautilus, you can use the **Ctrl** + **H** shortcut to display them

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu most of a user's configuration files can be found inside `~/.config`.

The configuration file for Code::Blocks, `default.conf` is in `~/.config/codeblocks` (i.e., `/home/$USER/.config/codeblocks`).

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
locate codeblocks | grep .conf$
```

The output should be:

```
~/.config/codeblocks/default.conf
```

This means that `default.conf` is at:

```
$HOME/.config/codeblocks/default.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

After you finish building and running your first project and select *File* -> *Quit* to quit Code::Blocks, Code::Blocks will ask you if you want to save the changes to the Code::Blocks default perspective.

[image: IMG:]

If you click the *Yes* button, Code::Blocks will create a new default.conf file in `~/.config/codeblocks/`. It will also create a few additional new files in `~/.config/codeblocks/`.

default.conf
  *xx_XX*_personaldictionary.dic
  codesnippets.ini
  DragScroll.ini

After Code::Blocks has created the Code::Blocks default perspective for the first time, it will not prompt you to create it again.